# Keras: How to access step in model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

**Is there a way to access the current Keras training step as a tensor in the tensorflow graph?**

I am trying to build a model which has an 'epsilon' parameter which is decayed as a function of the current training step.

```
epsilon = some_fn_of(K.global_step) # <- Something like this?
self.q = K.Sequential([
    K.layers.InputLayer(input_shape),
    K.layers.Dense(n, name='q'),
    K.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.cond(tf.random.uniform((), 0, 1) < epsilon,
        lambda _: tf.constant(0.0),
        lambda ac: ac)
], name='q')
```

FYI: I'm using the Tensorflow bundled Keras.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will work for all purposes, but it looks like you can find the next training step number using `model.optimizer.iterations`. The variable name appears to have the format "<optimizer name>/iter:0". You can find the `iterations` property in the [Optimizer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/optimizers/Optimizer) documentation. Example value:

```
<tf.Variable 'Adam/iter:0' shape=() dtype=int64, numpy=5978>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that Keras does not have any such tensor in the graph and that the only way to access the step is through Callbacks ([Keras Docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/),Tensorflow Docs). Especially since Keras is meant to be agnostic to the backend, and so would likely maintain the step outside of tensorflow.